# Extension of finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following problem. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $a$ be a primitive $16$th root of unity over the field $F$. Determine the dimension $[F(a):F]$ when $F$ is:

(a) The field of $9$ elements,

(b) The field of $7$ elements,

(c) The field of $17$ elements,

(d) What can you say in the case $p = 2$?

My understanding is that since $a$ is a primitive root of unity, $a^{16} - 1 = 0$ is the minimal polynomial. Thus by Proposition 1.4 of Lang's Algebra book, $[F(a):F]$ is equal to $16$. However, I know this isn't correct since this answer doesn't depend on the number of elements in $F$.

Comment: $x^{16}-1$ cannot be the minimal polynomial, because it is not irreducible: it factors as $(x-1)(x^{15}+x^{14}+\cdots+1)$.

Comment: Ohh I see, how would we use the number of field elements to determine the minimal polynomial then?

Comment: Because the multiplicative structure of the field tells you how many roots $x^{16}-1$ already has in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ is a primitive 16th root of unity, it is a root of the so-called 16th cyclotomic polynomial:
$$\Phi_{16}(a) = a^8+1$$

a) notice that $a^4=-1$ has $4$ roots in $\mathbb{F}_9$, note them as $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$, then
$$\Phi_{16}(a) = (a^2)^4+1 = (a^2-\alpha_1)(a^2-\alpha_2)(a^2-\alpha_3)(a^2-\alpha_4)$$
The minimal polynomial of $a$ is one of those four factors, so $[\mathbb{F}_9(a):\mathbb{F}_9] = 2$.

b) let $\alpha = a^4$, then $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^2 + 1 = 0$.

Because $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}_7$, we have $[\mathbb{F}_7(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_7] = 2$.

Then we find that $(2\alpha + 2)^2 = \alpha$ and $(3\alpha - 2)^2 = 2\alpha + 2$, so
$$[\mathbb{F}_7(a^2):\mathbb{F}_7(\alpha)] = [\mathbb{F}_7(a):\mathbb{F}_7(a^2)] = 1$$
Therefore $[\mathbb{F}_7(a):\mathbb{F}_7] = 2$.

c) $a^8+1 = 0$ has all $8$ roots in $\mathbb{F}_{17}$, so $[\mathbb{F}_{17}(a):\mathbb{F}_{17}] = 1$.

d) in the case $p=2$(I suppose it means the field has characteristic $2$), $a^{16}-1=(a-1)^{16}$, which has a root $a=1$ of multiplicity $16$. Therefore the extension has degree $1$.

Comment: I think for part (a) it should be $(a^2 - \alpha_1)(a^2 - \alpha_2)(a^2- \alpha_3)(a^2- \alpha_4$. 
For part (b) how did you conclude that $F_7(a^2):F_2(\alpha)] = [F_7(a): F_7(a^2)] = 1$  from $(2\alpha+2)^2 = \alpha$ and $(3\alpha - 2)^2 = 2\alpha + 2$? Should there be an $a$ in these relations somehwere?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the minus sign in part (a). In part (b) it was because $\alpha = a^4$,

Comment: I also wanted to ask for part (b) how you arrived at the identity $2\alpha + 2)^2 = \alpha$ and $(3\alpha - 2)^2 = 2\alpha + 2$. Does it have to do with the characteristic of the field? Also, for part (c) how do you know that all the roots are in the field?